# Inkscape, 300dpi image for printing, 2"x2" - export settings

Tags: print-design, inkscape, export, resolution, dpi

It was requested of me to provide a 300dpi image for printing at a resolution of 2"x2". I have been scouring the forums and am more confused than ever. My image is easily scalable in Inkscape and will look good at whatever size I make it to be, but I have no idea how large to make my .png export (the request said that png was fine).

I understand that 300dpi is not the default in Inkscape and also that the dpi used in Inkscape doesn't necessarily correspond to the dpi in printing at any case.

I just need to know - given the requirements above, can someone advise me on how to set the settings in Inkscape to get the export I need?

I believe and fear on reading some of these forums that it may not be that simple, but given I know the size I need and the printing resolution, and (I am pretty sure in the case of this particular image) that it doesn't matter what size/dpi the image was created at, I was hoping for a straightforward answer if at all possible.

I can resize the actual image if I need to before doing the export, no problem. So between resizing the image and the proper settings, I am hoping that this is not too difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog box is very clear:

File > Export bitmap

In the dialog box choose units: **Inches**

Below will say: width: 600, height: 600 (this is the size in pixels)

and little to the right will say 300 ppi. (this is the print resolution)

---

#### The math behind it is very simple

2 inches, at 300 pixels each inch = 2x300 = 600 px.

Comment: Thank you! That was extremely helpful. I had actually figured this out since I posted but I wasn't sure, and this was great confirmation.